# Why the a variable doesn't properly represent the total cents of a? Why there is 1 value less in than it should be?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    

    double a= 10.12;
    int cents= (int)(a*100);
    printf("%d\n",cents);
    printf("%.15lf", a);
    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
1011
10.119999999999999
```

Comment: Floating point can't represent `10.12` precisely, so the actual value is `10.119999999`. Use `round()` instead of `(int)`

Comment: I think that's a floating point error, that, when converted to an integer, was rounded down.  
I found an explanation of floating point errors [here](https://blog.penjee.com/what-are-floating-point-errors-answered/) but didn't read it.

Comment: Consider reworking your code to something along the lines of `int a = 1012; int dollars = a / 100; int cents = a % 100; printf("$%d.%02d\n", dollars, cents);`